# Michael Hartl's Rails 5 tutorial chapter 10, listing 10.56, test if the admin attribute is forbidden

Tags: ruby, testing, tdd, ruby-on-rails-5

I was trying to pass the exercise in [listing 10.56](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/updating_and_deleting_users//)  and test if the admin attribute is forbidden.
I added admin parameter in

**app/controllers/users_controller.rb**

```
def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation,
                                   :admin)
end
```

also, filled necessary parts in

**test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb**

```
test "should not allow the admin attribute to be edited via the web" do
      log_in_as(@other_user)
      assert_not @other_user.admin?
      patch :update, id: @other_user, user: { password: "",
                                              password_confirmation: "",
                                              admin: true }
      assert_not @other_user.reload.admin?
 end
```

Still, I am getting unknown error after test:

```
ERROR["test_should_not_allow_the_admin_attribute_to_be_edited_via_the_web", UsersControllerTest, 3.2600422599352896]
 test_should_not_allow_the_admin_attribute_to_be_edited_via_the_web#UsersControllerTest (3.26s)
URI::InvalidURIError:         URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): http://www.example.com:80update
            test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:37:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
```

Anyone here was dealing with the same problem?

Answer (score 3):

This error is intended. As the exercise says you added `:admin` to permitted params before.

Your test now will send the patch request and set `admin: true` for @other_user (which is possible here, since you added `:admin` to permitted params). After that you use `"assert_not"` which will raise the error, since the test expects that

```
@other_user.reload.admin?
```

will be false but in your case its true. Deleting `:admin` from permitted params in `app/controllers/users_controller.rb` will change your test to green.

Answer (score 1):

The following should give you a non-erroring test that will fail when you allow admin to be altered as you have.

```
test "should not allow the admin attribute to be edited via the web" do
      log_in_as(@other_user)
      assert_not @other_user.admin?
      patch user(@other_user), params: { 
                               user: { password: "",
                                       password_confirmation: "",
                                       admin: true }
      assert_not @other_user.reload.admin?
 end
```